# Possible Next Step after Development Phase on Divi module plugin

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, module

I created a custom Divi Module Plugin for Instagram Gallery. The plugin is works fine on development mode under "yarn start" or "npm start" command. **I need to deploy/build the plugin without initializing yarn/npm dev server**. Is this possible, because the plugin doesn't run on Divi Visual Builder as React needs a compiler to be able to get running.

I created the plugin using https://github.com/elegantthemes/create-divi-extension template. I already looked for possible deployment but no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the extension for production using "yarn build" or "npm run build"

Check this link for more information. https://github.com/elegantthemes/create-divi-extension